# Android 7 webview not loading urls after some time

Tags: android, webview, chromium, android-7.0-nougat, webviewclient

we are experiencing a weird issue in our mobile app with devices running Android 7., although 6. are working fine for the same code.

Users can navigate through different urls successfully in the embedded webview we have in our app but at some point the webView stops working. Any new navigation requested through webView.loadUrl(String url) simply notifies us about the start of the process through WebViewClient.onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) but then nothing happens. We've seen through device inspection in chrome tools that the request is stuck in "pending" state and never progresses. It does not matter if it was an existing webView or a brand new one; from that moment on any invocation of webView.loadUrl(String url) does nothing :(

WebView integration with Chrome is one of the major changes in Android 7, so we suspect that could be related somehow to this behaviour.

Falling back to the previous WebView implementation does not seem possible either.

Any ideas or alternative approaches you can think of regarding this?

Comment: Add permision Manifest file.  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: @RatilalChopda I already have the permission, otherwise it would never work, which is a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

We isolated the problem to devices with Chrome version 62.0.3202.84. Updating to the next stable version, 63.0.3239.83 fixes the problem. Holy...